# Knockout Mapping attempt not mapping with JSON responses

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am new to knockout and cannot seem to get a simple mapping to work at all. I am in an MVC4 C#.

My View looks like such:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Simple Mapping Example</h2>

The time on the server is: <span data-bind="text: ServerTime"></span>
and <span data-bind="text: NumberOfUsersConnected"></span> user(s) are connected.

@section Scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function ViewModel() {
            var self = this;

            self.ServerTime = ko.observable();
            self.NumberOfUsersConnected = ko.observable();
        }

        var vm = new ViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(vm);

        $.getJSON('/Mapping/GetServerInfo', function(data) {
            ko.mapping.fromJSON(data, {}, vm);
        });

    </script>
}
```

Example JSON that is returned from the controller call 'Mapping/GetServerInfo' is:

```
{"ServerTime":"2013-03-13T14:24:10.5675104-07:00","NumberOfUsersConnected":5}
```

For the data-binds I have tried text and value, neither one causes any data to be bound and displayed.

Am I missing something really obvious?

As per the question in the comments yes this is what is in my Layout.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/knockout-2.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you referenced KO and KO.mapping in your layout? Does the @RenderSection("Scripts") come after the @RenderBody and script includes?

Comment: Updated original question. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `$.getJSON` [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

> The success callback is passed the returned data, which is typically a
>   JavaScript **object or array as defined by the JSON structure and parsed
>   using the $.parseJSON() method.**

So your the `data` variable is holding an already parsed object so you need to use the `ko.mapping.fromJS` method:

```
$.getJSON('/Mapping/GetServerInfo', function(data) {
   ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, vm);
});
```

Comment: Yeah I figured this out. Thanks for the reply.